# Cannot access new azure databases created using SQLAzureMW.exe

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I've just used the `SQLAzureMW.exe` migration tool to copy a `SQLServer 2008 R2` on premise database (schema and data) into an SQL server in a new azure trial account.

After fixing a few red flags in the script, it appeared to complete without error and I can see the database name in the azure portal (under the SQL server) and in SSMS on a local machine.

However, that's as far as I get.

In the Azure portal, if I click on the database name (under the SQL server), I get a message

> Access denied. You do not have access. Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.  - I am the owner.

In SSMS, I can connect to the Azure server and see the database but it contains no objects except system objects.

Also in Azure Portal, whilst the database shows up under SQL Servers > Servername > Databases,  it does not show up in "SQL Databases". I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Firewall rules seem to be OK.

Can anybody help with what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS,you are seeing no objects because you don't have the right access,error message is  thrown by Azure portal,but SSMS is showing only objects for which you have access

In Azure, databases are logically mapped under a SQLServer and you will be creating an Administrator Password while creating first database..Can you try logging in with that password..

Once you are able to login with that Username and password,you will be able to create logins and users specific for your database

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies. This issue is now resolved.

I eventually managed to contact the Microsoft Azure Support team and their engineer did some kind of re-sync. I then re-executing the migration script which did a whole load more processing than before and created the majority of our database objects in Azure. The only ones missing are ones flagged by the script as having compatibility issues. So my next task is to work through these issues.